# Why tomcat page not showing in firefox and chrome?

Tags: tomcat

I have tomcat server running and I am able to load the welcome page and my application using internet explorer but from some reason in both chrome and firefox I get HTTP Status 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like internet explorer was caching the page. Try emptying the cache and then hard reload, you should get 404 for internet explorer as well.

Comment: I've deleted the cache, the localhost:8080 return 404 and localhost:8080/app_name is working fine in IE.

Comment: Also, the folder \conf\Catalina\localhost is empty after starting tomcat

Comment: Are you noticing the same behaviour in other browsers?